# DBUS Access Denied

Tags: debian, d-bus

I am trying to trouble shoot a multi-part application that communicates between its different branches with DBUS. This application has been working great for years, but after a recent power outage, things went wrong.

I think I have traced the issue back to this error which occurs whenever I try to send a message on the system bus with qdbus

```
Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied Rejected send message
```

I went to the policy file for the process suspecting that it was too restrictive. Nothing has changed in these files, but even so, I thought it was a good lead. Even after I tried the most permissive policy that I could think of, I still got a similar error.

Here is the policy I tried, located at /etc/dbus-1/system.d/application.conf

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">

<busconfig>
  <policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="*" eavesdrop="true">
    <allow eavesdrop="true"/>
    <allow own="*"/>
    <allow user="*"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

I don't know what else to try. Any ideas?